# User copies answers (with suspicious upvotes)

Tags: support, abuse

https://stackoverflow.com/users/16579850/google

This user copied two answers:

- [Unable to start a micro front-end app in single-SPA application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470429/unable-to-start-a-micro-front-end-app-in-single-spa-application/68625937#68625937) is copied from this [Unable to start a micro front-end app in single-SPA application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470429/unable-to-start-a-micro-front-end-app-in-single-spa-application/68620425#68620425)
- [How do merge 2 lists of different lengths in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210534/how-do-merge-2-lists-of-different-lengths-in-python/68625885#68625885) is copied from [How do merge 2 lists of different lengths in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210534/how-do-merge-2-lists-of-different-lengths-in-python/57210701#57210701)

Both answers were upvoted very quickly. I don't think these upvotes are legitimate.

**Update**

The answers are deleted now, but the account still says '2 votes cast'. Can you still vote if you've been cheating?

Comment: I believe instead of asking this on Meta you should have flagged the answer if you felt the upvotes were really suspicious?

Comment: Well, this can usually be solved with a mod flag

Comment: too bad mod flag handling times are in the range of 1-2 months depending on the flag. I really hope there's an election right around the corner

Comment: I already flagged the answers because they were copied. But because these upvotes are suspicious I thought an additional action was the right way to do. I searched on meta and read that mods can't see details about upvotes.

Comment: that's true to an extent. What I was told a while ago is that mods can see the relationship between voters after a certain threshold, so they can do some work. The bulk of vote fraud handling still falls on the CMs (who are employees, not volunteers). Mods often escalate these cases to the CMs, so flags are still appropriate.

Comment: Meta, on the other hand, cannot do *anything* about them (except apply the Meta effect, which is rarely useful).

Comment: Strange close reason. Surely there are other meta posts about plagiarism (internal or external)(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sure, there are other meta posts about plagiarism. But the ones that *report* plagiarism are almost always closed in favor of a mod flag. Not sure about the close reason either, but when all you're given are nails...

Comment: This is one of those moments where I start to think about what "Does not seek input" actually means. I mean let's face it: you did what you had to do, you mod flagged it. But that wasn't enough because you are a human being and there was probably a little adrenaline coursing through your veins at the time; you came to meta to gather witnesses and validation. I can *fully* relate to that need. Is that not seeking input? I... don't know!

Comment: Thanks @Gimby! I flagged it, but I wasn't sure it was enough. I wasn't sure mods could see voting details. And I'm still not sure; while the answers are deleted, the profile still counts 2 given upvotes.

Comment: Score from upvotes is only kept for >=3 upvotes and if the post was deleted 60 days later. In this case both criteria don't hold and the account is at zero (well... 1)

Comment: I mean that this user has cast 2 votes. I suspect this user has given upvotes to another user, but not to another person. (if the votes were cast on my posts, please ignore this comment ;)).

Comment: *"too bad mod flag handling times are in the range of 1-2 months depending on the flag"* I do agree, @Zoe , lately I've noticed that flag handling times does seem to be all over the place. I, personally, flagged a user a week ago for what appeared to be voting irregularities and that flag has already been handled, and the user's suspension ends later today. On the other hand, I have a flag about plagiarism like the above from 03 July, and it's still pending. Though, I'm sure I saw one of the Staff members saying there isn't an election planned at the moment. :(

Comment: @Larnu yep. I set up a bot that pings /election/13 every 6 hours to keep an eye on when that changes. I have a relatively urgent redaction flag that has been pending since the 19th. Now it doesn't really matter anymore, the damage has been done. I've had plagiarism flags pending for 1-2 months. I also have some about 6 month old inside information indicating that there's only a couple mods actually handling flags atm, for a number of various reasons. You'd think these things combined would be enough to plan a new election :')